# how to assign the string value to listbox selectd value

Tags: c#, listbox

I want to select the listbox item when i ll given a string. That string name is on of the listbox item. How to assign a string to listbox selected item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using Listbox.Text, [Listbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.text.aspx)
searches for the item within the ListBox that matches the specified text and selects the item.

```
ListBox.Text= "string Value" ;
```

Comment: foreach (ListItem item in lbxempname.Items)
                        {
                           string neww =Convert.ToString(item);
                            if (Convert.ToString(item) == Givenstring)
                        {
                            item.Selected = true;
                            this.imgbtnedit_Click(null, null);
                        }
                       
                    }

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this :

```
foreach (var item in ListBox.Items)
{
   if (item.Text.Contains(stringToBeSearched))
   {
       //select item in the ListBox
       ListBox.SelectedValue = item.Value;
       break;
   }
}
```

Hope this helps .